# Run JavaScript when Angular controller has loaded DOM

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular template with an ng-repeat. That ng-repeat loads up textareas which I would like to autosize based on their contents. In order to do that, I need to initialize a plugin on each textarea element. The problem is the textareas need to exist in order to run the script on them, and unless I set a timeout I don't know when/where to run that init call. I need to run it once the controller has run and the ng-repeat has loaded up all the textareas into the DOM. I can't seem to find an event that fires when a controller is done doing it's thing.

This seems like such a common thing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put this script in a directive and put it on the ng-repeat. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410896/angularjs-directive-input-width-resize-by-keyup) to a question that has a pretty good explanation on how you might get started.

```
<div class="MyTextArea" ng-repeat="text int texts" my-directive>{{text}}</div>
```

Comment: I ended up making a directive called "autoResize" and putting it on the textarea itself. Then inside the directive, I run the plugin on the passed in element inside of scope.$watch().